# IIS 10 Application Pool stops responding with PHP REST API

Tags: php, iis, application-pool

I have a php-based REST API running on a web server installed on a Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.0. The web API is servicing an App used by many employees. The app can make requests to the server every minute, sometimes multiple times a minute, so in

Every few days, sometimes multiple times a day, the api stops responding, and the only way to get it back is to stop and start the Application Pool.

There is no message in the Event Viewer related to it. There is no error in the PHP log. The last calls that are made when the API stops responding are the same calls that have been made multiple times before.

I am at a loss as to what to look for next to figure out what could cause the issue. Is there any config in the Application Pool settings or in PHP that I could have missed? Would the number of requests made to the API be an issue (at the moment it seems like it should handle it, we're talking about a request every 2-3 seconds at the busiest)?

Any suggestions on what to look for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hang dumps of both `w3wp.exe` and `php-cgi.exe` might help determine the culprit, https://blog.lextudio.com/who-should-be-contacted-for-php-on-iis-issues-c80b90bd365 But I don't think it would be easy for you to pursue because of the technical experience required. Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and ask for guidance. I don't think the answer below would help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your API crashed several times and Rapid-Fail Protection was triggered. It prevents the failing application pool from getting into a continuous loop of crashing. This is useful when an application goes out of control which could overload the server.
In general, it is better to review the application code to resolve crashes, but you can also disable Rapid-Fail protection by right clicking on the Application Pool>Advanced Settings>Rapid-Fail Protection>(Enabled/Disabled).

Comment: Thanks, I tried disabling Rapid-Fail tonight actually. Hopefully it fixes something.

I am not sure I understand though how the API could crash without having any error in the PHP error logs or in the Event Viewer